# Read local sqlite file

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I need to read local sqlite file that on my iPad, I do not need the queries just how to open it, some starting point. I downloaded the file from FTP server and it located in my app.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: By the way, [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) can simplify your Objective-C SQLite programming, rather than using the [SQLite C API](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening and closing an SQLite database is not that hard.  You just need to follow a few steps:

**Step 1 - copy the database out of your bundle into your app's documents folder.**

You don't want to be tinkering with the bundle version of the database, you want to use a specific instance for *this* device.

```
//*******************************************
- (void)copyDatabaseToDocumentsFolder {
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localDatabase = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"YourDatabaseFileName.sql"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: localDatabase];

    if (fileExists == NO) {
        NSError *err;

        // Get the path to the database in the application package
        NSString *databaseInAppBundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"YourDatabaseFileName.sql"];

        // Copy the file from the package to the users filesystem
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: databaseInAppBundle toPath: localDatabase error: &err]) {
            NSLog(@"Database copy failed:  %@", [err description]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2: - create an iVar for the database.**

```
@interface YourClass () {
    sqlite3 *localDB;
}

@end
```

**Step 3 - open and close as needed.**

```
//*******************************************
- (void)closeDatabase {
    if (localDB != nil) {
        sqlite3_close(localDB);
        localDB = nil;
    }
}

//*******************************************
- (void)openDatabase {
    if (localDB == nil) {
        NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        char *dbpath = (char *)[[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"YourDatabaseFileName.sql"] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_open(dbpath, &localDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, bad copy and paste.  I've updated the code above.

Comment: Looks like the [OP is having issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041238/open-db-in-documents-folder) with your `openDatabase` method, which I would expect to return `BOOL` to indicate success.  Might be worth updating your code.