# Open DB in documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I have an sqlite file in my documents folder (I cheched and it's there). The issue is that the function openDatabase always prints Yes, even if I give it wrong path, so this is wierd.
The second thing is

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(localDB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

it always goes to else and print "Error on SQLITE_OK". Can you please help me with my code:

```
@interface SQLReader ()
{
sqlite3 *localDB;
}

@end

@implementation SQLReader

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self openDatabase];

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSString *querySQL =  @"SELECT * FROM Animations";
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(localDB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            NSLog(@"%@",addressField);
            NSLog(@"%@",phoneField);

        }
        else
        {
           NSLog(@"%s","Match not found");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s","Error on SQLITE_OK");
    }

}


- (void)openDatabase
{

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    char *dbpath = (char *)[[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Bemad/IR_World/DB/IRRMobile.sqlite"] UTF8String];
    BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open(dbpath, &localDB);
    NSLog(openDatabaseResult ? @"DB: Yes" : @"DB: No");
}
```

Comment: What is the sqlite error when it fails? (hint: use `sqlite3_errmsg()`).

Comment: Lets just address the first issue, how openDatabase is always Yes?? Even if the path is wrong

Comment: Well `sqlite3_open()` doesn't return `BOOL` for a start...

Comment: `sqlite3_open` will create a database if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, better check my path